# How to create a new object in the row bellow each time I press the button with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

this code add just one new product when you press "new product" I know that the problem is when the loop end the value of the row takes its initial value instead of the new value so it keep creating products on top of each others so I know where the problem is but I don't know how to fix it

```
    from tkinter import *

    screen = Tk()
    screen.title("Buyer")
    screen.geometry("800x600")
    w = Frame(screen)
    w.grid(padx=1, pady=1)
    w.pack(pady=5)

    class product:
        def __init__(self, image, name, price, quantity, save):
            self.image = image
            self.name = name
            self.price = price
            self.quantity = quantity
            self.save = save
        def product_row(self, row):
            self.image.configure(command=lambda: Add_image(self.image, row))
            self.save.configure(command=lambda: create_item(self.name, self.price))
            self.image.grid(column=0, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
            self.name.grid(column=1, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
            self.price.grid(column=2, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
            self.quantity.grid(column=3, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)
            self.save.grid(column=4, row=row, padx=30, pady=15)

    def create_product():
        add_image = Button(w, text="+", font=("helvetica", 30))
        add_name = Entry(w, font=("helvetica", 13))
        add_price = Entry(w, font=("helvetica", 16), width=5)
        add_quantity = Entry(w, font=("helvetica", 16), width=5)
        save = Button(w, text="save item", font=("helvetica", 13))
        return product(add_image, add_name, add_price, add_quantity, save)

    def new_product():
        row = 1
        while True:
            row += 1
            prd = create_product()
            prd.product_row(row=row)
            break

    def selling():
        buying_button.destroy()
        selling_button.destroy()
        screen.title("selling mode")
        btn = Button(w, text="switch", command=buying).grid(row=0, column=2, pady=15, padx=30)
        btn = Button(w, text="new product", command=new_product).grid(row=0, column=1, 
                                        pady=15, padx=30)

    buying_button = Button(w, text="buyer mode", font=("helvetica", 16), width=16, height=2)
    selling_button = Button(w, text="seller mode", font=("helvetica", 16), width=16, height=2,     
                                                                      command=selling)
    selling_button.pack()
    buying_button.pack()

    screen.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `grid_size` method to get information about the size of the grid. From the canonical documentation:

> Returns the size of the grid (in columns then rows) for container. The size is determined either by the content occupying the largest row or column, or the largest column or row with a -minsize, -weight, or -pad that is non-zero.

In `new_product` you can use this method to get the starting row.

```
def new_product():
    (columns, rows) = root.grid_size()
    row = rows+1
    prd = create_product()
    prd.product_row(row=row)
```